# PHP Setting URL Globally and Call it in every page

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I want all my hardcoded URL's will be saved in only 1 php file. Let's name it. Global.php
so whenever I have hardcoded variable URLs. I will save it on my Global.php.

For example.

```
define("MAIN", "http://mainpage.com");
define("LOGIN", "http://mainpage.com/login");
define("REGISTER", "http://mainpage.com/register"):
```

So for example. I have a Login Page..

I will try to used the Global defined URL so It can avoid hardcoded URLS..

Login.php

```
include'../Global.php';
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo REGISTER; ?>">REGISTER</a></li>     
                    <li><a href="<?php echo LOGIN; ?>">LOG IN</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Like above, but the problem is on my Global.php. The domain name "http://mainpage.com" is repeatedly used in Global.. 
What I want to achieve is to set the domain name in Global.php and the subdomain and directory file of every pages should be concatenate to the Global define Domain only.. 
How I can do this?

I have research another solution like this:

```
define("LOGIN", "/login");
define("REGISTER", "/register"):


include'../Global.php';
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo REGISTER; ?>">REGISTER</a></li>     
                    <li><a href="<?php echo LOGIN; ?>">LOG IN</a></li>
                </ul>
```

But there are times that whenever I click the Register, It directs to

```
http://mainpage/REGISTER
```

which is supposedly directs to

```
http://mainpage/register
```

Sometimes it directs to `http://mainpage/REGISTER` and sometimes it directs to `http://mainpage/register`

How I can avoid that?

I think what's best is.. 
for example..

In my Global.php
I think I should declare the domain page and just concatenate the Global domain page in every subdomain page of my page..

Just like this..

```
define("MAIN", "http://mainpage/");
```

And I want to concatenate the global define domain in every page that I have hardcoded URLS. How I can achieve it?

For Example
On my index.php (MAINPAGE)
There is a button there that named `LOGIN` and `REGISTER`

So in my code.. 
I want to be it like this..

```
include'../Global.php';
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo REGISTER . (Whatever subdomain name that register is and concatenate to global define domain); ?>">REGISTER</a></li>        
                    <li><a href="<?php echo LOGIN . (Whatever subdomain name that login is and concatenate to global define domain); ?>">LOG IN</a></li>
                </ul>
```

I have different page for LOGIN and REGISTER..
But I think, I was mistaken by concatenating the Global Define Domain to subdomain and directory file.. 
How to get the subdomain and directory file of a page and put it into a variable and concatenate it to the Global define

Can somebody help me?

Comment: The `REGISTER` in links happens when the constant is _not_ defined before you use it. Then php _assumes_ that you mean the string `REGISTER`, since no such constant exists. PHP actually warns you about that, so it looks like you disabled or ignore such warnings, which is not a good idea...

Comment: For the rest: it make sense to usually use links tha tonly contain an absolute path (sometimes even a relative path) and _not_ the domain, since that way your code is portable between domains. The browser will take care to add the current domain. The only exception should be links to other domains. In that case obviously the browser cannot help, you have to use full URLs.

Comment: In my Global.php I have define("terms", "http://mainpage.com/Terms"); sometimes when I click the Terms page.. It directs to mainpage.com/terms which is wrong, it should be on mainpage.com/Terms

Comment: Exactly the same as above: obviously in that case the constant is not defined, probably simply because that file `Global.php` has not been included or is included only later. Oh, btw: using mixed case in URLs is a bad idea to rely on... (in the path part, not in query args)

Comment: So what I am gonna do?? All I want is to remove hardcoded URLs and set it in Global.. So whenever I will change directory file of a page.. I will just open the Global and change it, not to open all pages and find all hardcoded urll

Comment: What kind of question is that? Your file `Global.pph` is not included, so the constants are not defined in those cases! What answer do you expect? Did you even read my comments?

Comment: Arkascha, Global.php is included for every page that I will use a defined URL..

Comment: Here is my Global.php pastebin.com/A6HPS2Kb.. Here is my footer.php pastebin.com/XDUrtHFL –  Iron Programmer

Comment: When I sometimes click the Terms link. It go to mainpage.com/terms.. It should be direct to mainpage.com/Terms

Comment: There are times that, it directs to the correct page, sometimes its not.

Comment: Check what is actually coded in the links. Not by clicking on them (I mentioned before that mixed case in URLS is a very bad idea...), but by examining the link. Do that with a right click, then select "inspect element". What is coded in the links when they lead to the wrong target? The correct or the wrong spelling? I bet the wrong one.

Comment: I inspect elements the terms.. this is what I saw.. ?<a href="terms">Terms &Conditions</a>?

Comment: Yep, as expected. So the link has been constructed by not using the constand which means the `define()` has not been executed. You can make another test: change the `define("terms", "mainpage.com/Terms")` to something where you use something else instead of "Terms", maybe ".../XXXTermsXXX" and try again. I _bet_ you will _not_ see `XXXtermsXXX` in the link, but again `terms`. I _bet_ because I am sure that the constant is _not_ defined.

Comment: Maybe the `include` does not work. Did you check your http servers error log file for that?  The relative path to `../Global.php` could be wrong. also, beside the _urgent_ hint _not_ to use mixed case URLs (!) I suggest you stick to the general pattern of using capitals for constants (so `TERMS`, not `terms`).

Comment: Hello Arkascha.. It works.. :) But my teacher advise me that, it is good if in your global.php.. there is only one defined hardcoded url and. Get the subdomain of every page and concatenate it with the global define domain..

Comment: Global defines are generally considered evil and very dangerous. Especially if you do not stick to accepted programming habits of at least using all-capitals for constants. I would generally advise _against_ using `define()` at all for this. At least in a global scope. you can use constants, but in OOP manner as class constants.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing occurs because your `REGISTER` constant uses domainless links that start with `/` that means it will take current domain and add link to it.

To solve that you can load `Global.php` file and then define `REGISTER` constant using already defined domain name.

For example:

```
include'../Global.php';
// notice that you need to include global.php before using MAIN constant
define("LOGIN", MAIN . "/login");
define("REGISTER", MAIN . "/register");
```

Comment: Hello. Insanebits, I tried your advise..                                               define("LANDING", "http://mainpage.com");
    define("terms", LANDING . "/Terms");
    define("aboutus", LANDING . "/AboutUs");
    define("contactus", LANDING . "/ContactUs/contactform");

Comment: I have another file for footer.php 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php include'../GlobalConstant.php'; ?>
 <div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="twelve columns">
   <hr color="#0d2c87" width="100%">
     <ul>           
      <li><a href="<?php echo terms; ?>">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo aboutus; ?>">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo contactus; ?>">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>

Comment: when i try to click the Terms and Conditions. It directs to http://mainpage/terms which is wrong.. It should be in http://mainpage.com/Terms

Comment: even I added http:// It sometimes directs to mainpage/terms which is wrong.. It should be in mainpage.com/Terms

Comment: can you show exact situation where it fails to redirect correctly?

Comment: Here is my Global.php  http://pastebin.com/A6HPS2Kb.. Here is my footer.php http://pastebin.com/XDUrtHFL

Comment: When I sometimes click the Terms link. It go to mainpage.com/terms.. It should be direct to mainpage.com/Terms

Comment: All I want is to remove hardcoded URLs and set it in Global.. So whenever I will change directory file of a page.. I will just open the Global and change it, not to open all pages and find all hardcoded url

Comment: So i guess problem is that you're trying to include global.php from other directory than current and `../Global.php` doesn't include your file and then PHP uses undefined constant as a string. you can try including global php using absolute location

Comment: How I am going to include global in my footer.php as absolute location?

Comment: something like `include('/var/www/website/Global.php')` it will depend on your file system.

Comment: I tried it but when I access the site, it directs to another page, but when I try it again. it direct to wrong page.. How I am going to do this?  
All I want is to remove hardcoded URLs and set it in Global.. So whenever I will change directory file of a page.. I will just open the Global and change it, not to open all pages and find all hardcoded url

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply put this in your globals file:

```
<?php
  define("MAIN", "http://website.com");
  define("LOGIN", MAIN . "/login");
  define("REGISTER", MAIN . "/register");
```

And then in your other files:

```
<?php include "../Global.php"; ?>

<ul>
  <li><a href='<?php echo LOGIN; ?>'></a></li>
  <li><a href='<?php echo REGISTER; ?>'></a></li>
</ul>
```

That should work as intended if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Hello. Emanuel, I tried your advise.. define("LANDING", "mainpage.com"); define("terms", LANDING . "/Terms"); define("aboutus", LANDING . "/AboutUs"); define("contactus", LANDING . "/ContactUs/contactform");

Comment: I have another file for footer.php <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <?php include'../GlobalConstant.php'; ?> <div class="footer"> <div class="container"> <div class="twelve columns"> <hr color="#0d2c87" width="100%"> <ul> <li><a href="<?php echo terms; ?>">Terms & Conditions</a></li> <li><a href="<?php echo aboutus; ?>">About Us</a></li> <li><a href="<?php echo contactus; ?>">Contact Us</a></li> </ul> </div> </div> </div> </body> </html>

Comment: when i try to click the Terms and Conditions. It sometimes directs to mainpage/terms which is wrong.. It should be in mainpage.com/Terms

Comment: All I want is to remove hardcoded URLs and set it in Global.. So whenever I will change directory file of a page.. I will just open the Global and change it, not to open all pages and find all hardcoded url